# How to have cut like functionality in TCL/tk?

Tags: split, tcl

I have a input text file which I am processing using TCL/tk. The file has several parameters followed by their values. If a value is not available, N/A is printed next to parameter name.

For example,

```
Temperature : 27 deg C
Current     : N/A 
Voltage     : 200 V
```

I want to extract the value of each parameter, compare it with N/A and then take some action. So far I have written following code.

```
    set counter 0
    set value {split $result ":"}
    foreach rec value {
       if {counter == 1} {
          # Add logic here to confirm if we have value or N/A
       }
       incr counter 1
    }
```

I want to know if there is a simple or better way to do a cut (bash) like operation to directly get the value of the parameter in TCL/tk?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - you want something that will dump the contents of selected field as a list? Or I are you unsure on how to open the file and read it line by line?

Comment: normally I would do "echo $result | cut -d ':' -f2" in bash to do the same operation. I do not know if we have an equivalent way in TCL ($result contains one line from the file). I want to extract parameter values.

Comment: You mean `$(cut -d: -f2)`? How would you use it afterwards? `grep`? Checkout http://xyproblem.info - looks like you are not saying what you are actually trying to do, but rather what you think the solution is.

Comment: I think I have a solution. I want to know if there is an easier or built-in way to do the same.

Comment: In that case, reading line by line is the way to go in TCL. Does `result` in your example contain the entire file for example? That is not something I would do. I am still not sure what you meant to do in Bash, perhaps you should add to your answer what you would have done in Bash, and add how you initialize result. I am still not sure if I can answer or not as it is.

Comment: Not entirely sure either what you are trying to do, so I guess I'll show you [this ideone](https://ideone.com/JASzF3) which might be what you are looking for?

Comment: Yeah, $result contains one line from the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am still not completely sure what you are looking for, but I think this is rather idomatic, and I think better than dump reading everything and iterating again (and quite faster than regular expressions):

```
set fd [open "my_file"]
while { [gets $fd line] > -1 } { 
    lassign [split $line :] name value
    if { [string trim $value] == "N/A" } {
        #Something
    }
}
close $fd
```

`trim` handles extra spaces after the split. If you are using value more than once I would re-set it about the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a regular expression to do the line parsing. It's not strictly necessary, but this is at about the point where that's the clearest method:

```
# Not quite sure where the data is coming from, so I'll assume it's one big chunk
foreach line [split $all_output "\n"] {
    if {[regexp {^([^:]*[^:\s])\s*:\s*(.*)$} $line -> key value]} {
        if {$value ne "N/A"} {
            puts "key is '$key' and value is '$value'"
        }
    }
}
```

The critical thing here is the regular expression: `^([^:]*[^:\s])\s*:\s*(.*)$` It's got several bits:

1. `^` — Anchor at the start of the line.
2. `([^:]*[^:\s])` — Match (and remember) a sequence of non-colon characters where the last one is also a non-space. (This will be the `key` variable's contents.)
3. `\s*:\s*` — Match the separator; an arbitrary number (including none) of spaces, followed by a colon, followed by an arbitrary number of spaces.
4. `(.*)$` — Match (and remember) all characters from there to the end of the line. (This will be the `value` variable's contents.)

We do the check against `N/A` separately because checking that in the RE, while *possible,* is fairly miserable. And the `split $all_output "\n"` is a standard (and efficient) Tcl idiom for take a big multiline string and convert it into a list of smaller strings, one per line.

Comment: I could have done `split $line ":"` and then `string trim` on the pieces, but that starts to become less convenient.